# Error in uploading an image from your phone

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

When I upload an image from my phone to the app, I get the error:

> Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

and

> Access denied finding property

At the same time, everything loads normally from Google drive.

The permissions are available in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Updated: the file upload is triggered on the third attempt...

Comment: *Updated: the file upload is triggered on the third attempt...* If you can no longer reproduce the problem please delete the question.

Comment: the problem is relevant. The file is loaded with 3-4 attempts. A should load on the first attempt